# The white-space:normal; property is not working on the advance custom field text input

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a frontend form which is created using ACF fields. I want to show the whole text in the field while the user is inputting it. But instead of moving to the next line, the text starts scrolling back. I tried to apply the `white-space:normal` css property to it but it doesn't work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Wsf.png)